# random php code running in wrong page

Tags: php, google-chrome, session, cookies

I am currently working on the user login portion of my website. I've been testing on 3 browsers (Chrome, IE, FF). I have a standalone page that i am using (test.php) to create a cookie for testing purposes.

Example code:

```
session_start();
setcookie("log_token", "blah", time() + 60*60*24*7);

echo "\n<pre>";
print_r($_COOKIE);
echo "</pre>";
```

This is displaying properly on IE and FF.

```
Array
(
    [PHPSESSID] => 894ati3nr464gbvk41hjco6eu4
    [log_token] => blah
)
```

However, on google chrome i was getting

```
Array
    (
    )
```

I did some testing, and i found out i have some code in (index.php) that erases my session and cookie data when a certain test is not met. Verified and tested, i changed the name of the cookie to (login_token1) in (test.php), and i was now seeing this in chrome:

```
Array
(
    [log_token1] => blah
)
```

Meaning the session, and "log_token" are being destroyed from code in (index.php).
To further test this, i removed that code from (index.php), and retested "log_token" in chrome, and both the proper cookie, and the session id showed up.

My question: 
Why in the world is php code from index.php being called, when i run (test.php) directly.....
This makes absolutely no sense, as it doesnt happen in IE or FF. Any insight would be lovely.

Comment: Did you have another tab / window open with the index.php?

Comment: I sure dont. Just test.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suffered similar problem. Google Chrome makes a blind request for favicon.ico (or something similar) if you don't have real favicon setup in your mark up. If you have some redirection rules that route all requests to index.php (which is common practice lately), the request for the icon also goes though index.php. This was the cause for the problem in my case.

Comment: Yup, i just figured that out. I was using url rewrite, routing ^([^/]+)$ to index.php?page={R:1}. I had conditions set up for "Is Not A File" and "Is Not A Directory". For some reason that wasnt working, so i changed the expression to: ^([^/\.]+)$, to exclude (.) and i am now getting the proper results. Would anybody happen to know why this was still happening even while i have "Is Not A File" and "Is Not A Directory" set up as conditions?